# I made an inappropriate joke in my class. Should I apologize or just let it be?

Tags: etiquette, teaching

I am teaching introductory calculus, physics and programming to engineering students at a local college. Yesterday, at the end of a long day which involved a lot of programming, I ended up making a bad joke. Maybe I was simply tired after the long day, but I had one of those moments, which we all have a few times in our lives, where I said something, and the brain immediately realized that I should not have said it.

So, the context was that one of the students in my class was finally able to get a program to work after struggling for a long time with his code. I then said, in what was meant to be a joke: "That feeling you get when you finally get a code to work is the best feeling ever, isn't it? It's even better than sex!".

Cue awkward silence and tumbleweeds. Now, none of the students appeared to be offended, but I immediately realized, as mentioned above, that what I had said was in bad taste, and that the joke was inappropriate. The rest of the class went fine though, and none of the students came up to me after class to inform me that they had been offended. However, I have been bothered about this the whole day today, and I wondered if I should maybe apologize for the bad joke at the beginning of next class. Or would that simply make it worse? Would it be better for me to just let it be?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Made a joke in poor taste without thinking in front of students. Is there anything I can do to salvage myself?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/202088/made-a-joke-in-poor-taste-without-thinking-in-front-of-students-is-there-anythi)

Comment: This question seems a bit different from the one linked, actually.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Anyon. There is, indeed, good advice in the answers given there.

Comment: "I am teaching introductory calculus, physics and programming to engineering students" all in one class?

Comment: Azor Ahai: DIfferent classes of course, but many of the same students are in all classes.

Comment: I think this question urgently needs a country tag.

Comment: I don't think it's poor taste per se, it's just a very ''cringe'' attempt at humour.  That is why there is an awkward silence afterwards, as they just felt embarassed that you were trying to be funny.  If you delivered it with non-native timing and accent, that would probably be even worse.

Comment: I delivered the "joke" with a native accent, so that's not an issue at least :). I should also add that I've had many of these students since August, and I have a very good relationship with the class overall. I have received a lot of excellent feedback from my students. And, yes, they have laughed at my jokes in the past. But this time my attempt at humor felt completely flat. Deservedly so. It was absolutely cringe as you put it.

Comment: In my opinion this joke is totally fine, and you shouldn't feel awkward about it. A joking teacher is better than a teacher that makes a big deal from small things, even if some of the jokes are lame a little bit. But this joke wasn't even lame, it's just the humor of tired programmers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If these were grad students, I'd let it go. But, being that these are younger let me suggest that you lose little with a simple apology. Something like "Sorry I went off message and off color with my attempt at humor yesterday."

The issue here is that students, while technically adults, include some who are very inexperienced with sex and some might be offended, due to their upbringing. If a student thinks less of you for this it is a problem. A simple statement might alleviate that issue in their mind.

Again, you lose little by taking the high road.

I'm not surprised that no one complained to you. But you don't know if they complained to others. And if you are uncomfortable it is easy to get back to a better place. No need to make a big deal of it, however.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. In the link provided by Anyon above, the main suggestion seems to be to just let it go. However, based on your answer, I also see how it may be best to apologize. I don't have the class again until Wednesday, so I have some days left to think about it.

Comment: If you want to double down on the joke, add "I should have said 'better than chocolate'.

Comment: "I should have said 'better than chocolate'.... I don't know what was on my mind!"

Comment: Another way to double down on the joke, if you're comfortable with self-deprecating humor: "I realized too late that I should limit my conjectures to fields where I have expertise."

Answer (score 31):

> Now, none of the students appeared to be offended...

I'll suggest that you follow the advice in the [prior question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/202088/made-a-joke-in-poor-taste-without-thinking-in-front-of-students-is-there-anythi) and just forget it and move on.

If your observation is correct, then it doesn't sound like your students found the joke to be *offensive*, so much as simply *lame*. I think that bringing up your lameness a second time risks (1) cementing it further in their minds that you can act consistently cringey, and (2) possibly making people reflect for a longer time and deciding retroactively that they *should* have been offended and file a report.

You have the right to remain silent. Anything you say can be used against you in [dean's office/student affairs/title IX coordinator].

Comment: Thanks. This is really good advice!